# Handling multiple instances of the same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, entity-framework

I am currently developing an application in ASP.NET CORE 2.0

The following is the action inside my controller that get's executed when the user clicks submit button.

[image: Action inside the controller]

The following is the function that get's called the action

[image]

As a measure to prevent duplicate inside a database I have the function 
IsSignedInJob(). The function works

**My Problem:**

Sometimes when the internet connection is slow or the server is not responding right away it is possible to click submit button more than once. When the connection is reestablished the browser (in my case Chrome) sends multiple HttpPost request to the server. In that case the functions(same function from different instances) are executed so close in time that before the change in database is made, other instances are making the same change without being aware of each other.

Is there a way to solve this problem on a server side without being to "hacky"?

Thank you

Comment: please read the how to ask section of the website

Comment: disable the button once clicked and the reenable after task is complete

Comment: It is a good client side solution. I need a server side as well

Answer (score 5):

As suggested on the comments - and this is my preferred approach-, you can simply disable the button once is clicked the first time.

Another solution would be to add something to a dictionary indicating that the job has already been registered but this will probably have to use a lock as you need to make sure that only one thread can read-write at a time. A Concurrent collection won't do the trick as the problem is not whether this operation is thread-safe or not. The `IsSignedInJob` method you have can do this behind the scenes but I wouldn't check the database for this as the latency could be too high. Adding/removing a Key from a dictionary should be a lot faster.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Using client side only solution was my initial approach. However, following "do not trust anything on a client side" I decided to implement server side solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Icarus's answer is great for the user experience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47163232/209259) and should be implemented. If you also need to make sure the request is only handled once on the server side you have a few options.  Here is one using the [ReaderWRiterLockSlim class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

[HttpPost]
public async SomeMethod()
{
  if (cacheLock.TryEnterWriteLock(timeout));
  {
    try
    {
      // DoWork that should be very fast
    }
    finally
    {
      cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
  }
}
```

This will prevent overlapping DoWork code.  It does not prevent DoWork from finishing completely, then another post executing that causes DoWork again.

If you want to prevent the post from happening twice, implement the [AntiForgeryToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks), then store the token in session.  Something like this (haven't used session in forever) may not compile, but you should get the idea.

```
private const SomeMethodTokenName = "SomeMethodToken";

[HttpPost]
public async SomeMethod()
{
  if (cacheLock.TryEnterWriteLock(timeout));
  {
    try
    {
      var token = Request.Form.Get["__RequestVerificationToken"].ToString();
      var session = Session[SomeMethodTokenName ];
      if (token == session) return;
      session[SomeMethodTokenName] = token

      // DoWork that should be very fast
    }
    finally
    {
      cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
  }
}
```

Not exactly perfect, two different requests could happen over and over, you could store in session the list of all used tokens for this session.  There is no perfect way, because even then, someone could technically cause a OutOfMemoryException if they wanted to (to many tokens stored in session), but you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Try not to use asynchronous processing. Remove task,await and async.

Comment: That was my first approach and it had same results as well

Comment: async/sync makes no difference in this case.

Comment: got any solution Erik?